# Custom range for specific values on y axis in GNU plot

Tags: gnuplot

Let the y axis range be from 0 to 0.9 with the stepsize of 0.1. I can specify the `ytics` for these ranges using `set ytics 0,0.1,0.9`. In the same plot if I want custom step size say between 0.5 to 0.6 i.e.,the step size between 0.5 to 0.6 should be 0.01. how can this be specified? I also want to have the corresponding `ytics` for these values. How this can be achieved in GNU plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set ytics 0.0, 0.1, 0.9
do for [i=1:9] {
    set ytics add (0.5 + i/100.)     # major tic with label
}
```

or if you want minor tics instead (no label, shorter ticmark):

```
set ytics add (0.5 + i/100.   1)
```

Comment: @ Ethan Thank you for the solution. I later found that using `y2tics` instead of `ytics` is better. I am not able to generate the grid for `y2tics`. Can you please tell how this can be done? I am getting `unexpected or unrecognized token`  when `set grid {{y2tics}}`  is used as mentioned [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/node188.html).

Comment: It's `set grid y2tics`.   The documentation uses curly brackets to indicate something that is optional.